# Which java JDK is compatible with oracle instant client 10g

Tags: oracle, installation, java, oracle-10g-r2, oracle-8i

I'm an intern stuck trying to retrieve data from Oracle 8i (a database that is as as I am)

**The problem:**

I need to write a java script that pulls data from Oracle 8i into a newer server.  The last client that is compatible with Oracle 8i is Oracle client 10g (10g instant client is still available for free on Oracle's website).

Documentation is scarce about 10g client compatibility. My server currently does not have java installed and my question is what version of java is compatible with 10g client?

Answer (score 1):

Java does not use the Instant Client. If you want to connect an Oracle database from Java code, then you need the Oracle JDBC driver, not the Instant Client.

https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/application-development/jdbc/downloads/index.html

Example:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47966597/how-to-connect-java-with-oracle-8i-database-on-local-network

You will still need to find a place to download such ancient version of these though.

Comment: Thanks for the amazing thread on stackOverflow but The Instant Client Package - Basic comes with the JDBC driver (OJDBC14.jar and classes12.jar).  Aren't those the only driver files necessary to establish a connection?
https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/linuxx86-64soft-092277.html

Comment: @Nicolasome Yes, it could work. I was not aware that the Instant Client contained these and such old versions were still available for download.